# Apply drill through to matrix having dynamic axis as its axes in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix that has a column as a prediction bucket and row is coming from a dynamic axis value. If I drill through to one of the cross-sections of this matrix it shows me all the data falling in the segment of prediction bucket but is not filtering through the dynamic axis value.

For example, I have my rows as tenure bucket and column as prediction bucket and one of its cross-section shows that 8 people fall in that category. I.e., having prediction >75% and have a tenure <3 months. But if I drill through it shows all the people falling in >75% bucket but doesn't filter on the age bucket.

Matrix

[image: Table-Matrix]

Drillthrough

[image: Drillthrough]

Answer (score 0):

Create a join between all the columns used in Dynamic axis to that table which actually holds those columns. 
For eg
[Relationship view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifdcj.jpg)

as we can see that I have used payment method in the creation of my dynamic axis so I created a relationship from `X_AXIS_VALUE` to payment method. And it solves my problem.